# Modal doesn't show if user manually types in our url in address bar

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, referrer, allow-modals

The modal I've created displays when a user accesses our page from an external link (i.e. Google search result), but **if a user enters our site by manually entering our URL into the address bar, an error occurs and the modal doesn't appear.**

Here is my code:

```
  const siteUrl = ["website.com"];
  const referrer_hostname = new URL(document.referrer).hostname;

  if (siteUrl.includes(referrer_hostname)) {
    console.log("Don't Show Modal", document.referrer);
  } else {
    console.log("Show Modal", document.referrer);

    $( window ).on('load', function() {
      console.log("closure modal firing");
      $('#closureModal').modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false,
        show: true
      });
    });
```

the `#closureModal` is connected to the HTML of the modal.

Error: `(index):123 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL`

Comment: There's no referrer value in the case you described.

Comment: ah, so in this case I need an else if (!referrer_hostname) ?

Comment: Right. You can't really put must trust in the referrer value anyway; it's easily spoofed or blocked by browsers. Check it before you try to make a URL from it.

Comment: okay. what other method would you recommend for this instance where I need the modal to appear without a referrer and when coming in from external sites?

Comment: Well, if there are no true security issues it's not a big deal as long as you handle cases where it's missing or malformed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.referrer is an empty string "" when you enter the URL into the address bar. Try addign a validation:

```
const referrer_hostname = document.referrer !== "" ? new URL(document.referrer).hostname : "";
```

this allows you to avoid the TypeError